# Attribute missing at run time

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an iOS app that uses core-data.  My object model has a couple of entities each with attributes.  I have set the code gen to manual and created NSManagedObject subclasses.  The project complies without issue and runs as expected - with one exception.  One attribute of an object is not found at run time.  For example the code has

```
NSLog(@"A = %@", obj.A);
```

The following error appears in the log:

property 'A' not found on object of type 'obj *'

Since the project compiles as expected, I believe the generated NSManagedObject subclass generation is correct.  Seems like the model loaded to the simulator is incomplete.

To correct this I have tried:

- Running clean
- Re-running the "Create NSManagedObject Subclass..."
- Creating a new model version

Nothing seems to work.  This is the only attribute that seems to have this problem.  Other information:

1. XCode version is 11.5
2. I am running project on iPhone 11 simulator
3. The project is using CloudKit

I searched for this error online and did not find anything helpful.

Any and all help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are those the actual attribute and entity names, or examples.  Please show the actual names, and the class definition.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, the problem only appears in some spots.  For example in a view controller if I run the sample code the error occurs.  But I created a method of the subclass called dumptToLog that uses NSLog for each attribute and the error does not occur.

Comment: The entity is called Configuration and the attribute is called sendTo.  The error is 

property 'sendTo' not found on object of type 'Configuration *'
(void)NSLog(@"sendTo = =%@",config.sendTo);

Comment: Are you importing the .h file?  Does the .h file have `sendTo` defined?

Comment: Yes, I am importing the .h file.  I think the compile would fail if I didn't, correct?  This is why I find the problem so perplexing.

Comment: Looks like the problem is confined to accessing the object from the debugger.  I cannot access the attribute when stopped by a breakpoint, but there does not seem to be a problem accessing it from the program.